# Angular 2 ng module imports

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

What is the significance of imports metadata of ngmodule decorator, when we are importing files at top. Difference between both the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These imports are entirely different concepts.

The imports at the top of the file are TypeScript imports to make classes, interfaces and variables known to the current file and are not related to Angular2.

The `@NgModule()` imports are to make `exports: []` of the imported `@NgModule()`s known to the importing `@NgModule()` so that they applied to components of the importing module if selectors match.

Also `providers: []` of an imported module are added to the root scope of the injector (only when the module is not lazy loaded).

Comment: Hi, indeed the questions are the same, but I found extremely difficult to understand the third paragraph: "The @NgModule() imports are to make exports: [] of the imported @NgModule()s known to the importing @NgModule() so that they applied to components of the importing module if selectors match." Would you be so kind to explain that further?

Comment: Well I tried to find the answer into that article without success and I don't understand what you wrote. Could you explain clearly why do we have to import twice in Angular 2?

Comment: @user3646717 if you're familiar with .NET, treat the top `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` as adding DLLs into **References** at project level. Now this `@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],` is the `using` statement at top of each .cs file to explicitly tells what DLLs are used here. Hope this analogy will help.